# What is the homogeneous space $SU(2^n) / \otimes^n SU(2)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory

I apologize in advance, as I do not have any formal background in representation theory, but the following spaces have come up in interesting problems, and I am trying to understand them.  I am interested in the following two homogeneous spaces:

> (1)  $SU(2^n) / \otimes^n SU(2)$
>
> (2)  $U(2^n) / \otimes^n U(2)$

I believe that (1) has dimension (as a real manifold) $4^n -1 - 3^n$, and (2) has dimension $0$.

> *Question*:  Is there a standard way to compute what these spaces are?

In the case of (2), it should obviously be some discrete set of points but is it a single point, a finite set of points, or infinitely many points?  In the case of (1), the situation is significantly more complex.

Even knowing the homotopy or homology of these spaces would be interesting. Ultimately, I am **primarily interested in understanding the curvature of the spaces**.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You're viewing the denominators as direct products right? Then the dimension of the first is $4^n-1-3n$ and of the second is $4^n-1-4n$ (certainly not discrete). Asking how to "compute a space" is extremely broad, since so often the best answer in theory is "it is what it is." In the case of $U(4)/U(2)\times U(2)$, that's already the simplest nontrivial complex Grassmanian, which we can manage to compute $\pi_n$ of for $n\le4$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137210/what-are-the-first-8-homotopy-groups-of-the-complex-grassmannian-g-mathbbc2).)

Comment: @anon I am viewing the denominators as tensor products not direct products

Comment: I was under the impression that you were having the **direct product** of groups $SU(2)\times\cdots\times SU(2)$ act on the **tensor product** of vector spaces $\Bbb C^2\otimes\cdots\otimes\Bbb C^2$, and since the tensor product has dimension $2^n$ this makes the **direct product** a subgroup of $SU(2^n)$. There is no "tensor product of groups" that makes sense here. (Although I have seen many instances of authors incorrectly using $\otimes$ in physics this way.)

Comment: @anon I believe there is an irreducible representation of the tensor product in $SU(2^n)$, no?

Comment: Every representation of a compact group has an irreducible subrepresentation. Not sure where you're going with that. [Addendum to previous comment: I get why physicists abuse terminology in one situation though: given a representation $V$ of $G$ and $W$ of $H$, we can have the direct product $G\times H$ act on $V\oplus W$ or on $V\otimes W$. By writing $G\times H$ versus $G\otimes H$, this way physicists can distinguish between the two situations. That's understandable.]